# google transliteration suggestions not showing

Tags: javascript, api, transliteration

As i am working with api and it worked fine but not showing any suggestions in dropdown so i know that it deprecated by google is any other to showing suggestions in dropdown

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
google.load("elements","1",{packages: "transliteration"});

        $(document).on('ready',function(){


        $("textarea,input[type=text]:visible").addClass("oepl_translate_words");


function OnLoad(){
    var languagesettings = {
        sourceLanguage: google.elements.transliteration.LanguageCode.ENGLISH,
        destinationLanguage: [google.elements.transliteration.LanguageCode.GUJARATI],
        shortcutKey: 'ctrl+g',
        transliterationEnabled: true
    };

    var control = new google.elements.transliteration.TransliterationControl(languagesettings);
    console.log(control);
    var classname = document.getElementsByClassName("oepl_translate_words");
    //console.log(classname);
    control.ij(classname);

    //console.log(control);
}

google.setOnLoadCallback(OnLoad);
});
</script>

<textarea class="oepl_translate_words"></textarea>
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to remove unnecessary parts of the code. Only put a [mre] to replicate your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use this css style below:

```
.inputapi-transliterate-indic-suggestion-menu {
    color: #121111!important;  z-index: 99999!important; 
}
```